# Linux installation stops working after a few reboots

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, linux-mint

I'm trying to set up a dualboot Win8/Linux on my HP tablet (touchsmart tm2-1050ez).
However, when I'm finished setting it all up, after a few more reboots, I'm not able to boot to Linux anymore, as I keep getting the error

BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 23s! [swapper/0:1]

over and over again right after GRUB. I've left it sit for an hour, only to retrieve a screenful of these messages (only varying slightly in the time it's been stuck). Even recovery mode won't work.

So far I've tried Fedora 17, Ubuntu 12.10 and most recently Mint MATE 14, all of which have died in this exact fashion within a day of the original setup.

I've googled the problem, but all I could come up with was to run a BIOS update, which I already did and didn't help anything.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried completing the installation without installing any updates? The attempt here is to determine whether the problem is with the base system or an update.

Comment: Just tried that out, seems not to occur with out-of-the-box Mint 14. I'll try installing some of the packages I installed last before the issue occurred, one-by-one, hoping to find the culprit.

Comment: It's pretty much a sure bet the problem update is the kernel. Your Linux of choice might have a feature in its update manager to make it skip kernel upgrades, since that's a common desire for other reasons. (e.g. You have binary-only drivers for an older kernel and can't upgrade until those drivers get updated.)

Comment: I get what you mean, but it seems counterintuitive to me, as I always run all updates right after the initial setup, but the system continues to work and boot for a while after that. I'll give it a try though, thanks.

Comment: Probably a kernel bug, or bad ACPI tables. Unfortunately not the kind of things you can repair without solid expertise, you may be reduced to waiting for a kernel or firmware upgrade.

Comment: bad news, it's either not the kernel or the problem already exists on the stock version. Yesterday, I told apt to hold the kernel, then ran a full update and kept using it for 2 more hours, with at least 5 more reboots. Today I try starting it up again, bam, CPU stuck.

Is it possible that Linux is outright incompatible with this model of notebook? Could it be a hardware issue? What more can I try to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: Can we assume that it runs for days and days with Windows without problems?

Comment: (1) When that happen, on the next reboot to linux, try edit the grub line and add "acpi=off", see if that helps at all. (2) Can you boot into windows right after that CPU error?

Comment: That is the kind of thing that I have seen caused by a bad stick of RAM, but in your case that is not likely.  Sounds like you shouldn't be doing this unless you can find someone else with the same device as you that is doing the same thing.  Otherwise, its just guessing.

Comment: @djangofan the same here, but saw that on windows. If he has a windows partition that works OK, RAM shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Have you disabled FastBoot in Windows 8? If you didn't, your UEFI partition gets locked (except if you restart windows 8, shutdown still doesn't unmount it) and that might result in your Linux not booting. http://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting

Answer (score 1):

Please add `acpi=off noapic` to your boot parameters. It will disable any ACPI functions (that is the system that controls your dynamic speed fans, the power button behavior, sleep states, etc.). This verifies if your problem is related to energy functions.

Answer (score 0):

Edit Grub-Boot-Line and append to kernel-line:

```
coldplug DRV_DEBUG=verbose
```

to get information about when getting stuck (which module(s) loaded just before stuck).

Answer (score -2):

This has happened to me before. I was trying to install Linux on my Acer x64 bit laptop and I ran into those same issues. I didn't want to install, Ubuntu for Netbooks or install the Tablet version, wanted the actual Linux on my system. I honestly think installing regular Ubuntu or Fedora is too robust for tablet hardware and it isn't tested well on those machines since it's not too robust, especially the CPU and motherboard architecture is different although it says its x64 bit compatible.

Try looking at this distro:

```
http://puppylinux.org/wikka/Fatdog?redirect=no
```

Puppy linux is lighter and you get full command line access.

Also take a look at this before you download the .iso file

```
http://puppylinux.org/wikka/PPM
```